# static vector member variable

Tags: c++, vector, static

So I have a class with a static vector member:

```
class Foo {
// some private members
public:
static vector<Bar> MyVector;
};
```

Now I initialize MyVector before actually using it:

```
std::vector<Bar> Foo::MyVector;
```

Then I want to define a variable like this in main(), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Foo::MyVector::size_type t;
```

This workaround does work, but doesn't look beautiful (to my eyes):

```
vector<Bar>::size_type t;
```

What is the basic concept that I have been missing here?

**EDIT**

The main point is, should I always come back to see declaration of *MyVector* as  *vector< Bar>* before proceeding to declaring a size_type for it?

Comment: Have you tried this on *anything simpler* before? `std::string s; s::size_type n; // ???`

Comment: why it doesn't look beautiful to your eyes?

Comment: @OnurA. because I needed to scroll to the class for seeing declaration of MyVector

Comment: @Sourena then simply you can define it  with `using MyVector = vector<Bar>;`in C++11 or `typedef vector<Bar> MyVector;` in previous C++ versions so whenever you type MyVector you don't have to scroll back to the class for actualy declaration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not workaround. `MyVector` is object. `vector<Bar>` is type. `size_type` is typedef in `vector` class, not member variable.

Comment: So I need to go back to see the definition of Foo:MyVector in the class, before proceeding to defining a variable for storing its size_type?

Comment: @Sourena, no, by writing `vector<whatever_type>::size_type` you are accessing the size type of this particular vector _type_.

Comment: In C++11, you can use decltype(Foo::MyVector)::size_type

Comment: @MartinHierholzer interesting. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Sourena `decltype(Foo::MyVector)` will be the type of the variable `Foo::MyVector`, which is `vector<Bar>`. Thus `decltype(Foo::MyVector)::size_type` will be the same as `vector<Bar>::size_type`. You just gain a bit flexibility, since you do not need to assume the type at that point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`size_type` is a type declared in `std::vector`. It is bound to the class, not individual instances. Additionally, the :: operator is only used with namespaces and classes. You cannot use it with variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was just thinking if it is possible to "Extract" a typedef from an instance, and not going back to see its definition.